# C# Immediately after creating webdriver I get the message "no such window: target window already closed"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Windows 10
Selenium 3.141.0
Selenium Chrome Driver 87.0.4280.2000

```
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
```

After the `driver = new ChromeDriver();` is when I get the message.
This is being run in a Console Application for testing.
This is the full message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
   at WebDriverTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Source\Visual Studio\@POC\WebDriverTest\Program.cs:line 42
```

Comment: This is the full message:

Comment: What's your version of chrome? - You say your chromedriver is 87 - is chrome 87 as well?

Comment: Is anti-virus killing your browser process maybe?